# Adding image to <tspan>

Tags: jquery, image, tspan

I have this code:

```
<svg>
    <text>
        <tspan x='8' dy='16' id='china'>" + ¥5,000.00 + "</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

This shows me this: `¥5,000.00`

What I want is to show me with China flag, like this: [image]
Tried many ways, but can't. One was like:

```
<tspan x='8' dy='16' id='china'><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/INxnl.png'  width='20px' height='20px'>" + ¥5,000.00 + "</tspan>
```

Comment: please show all relevant code . Where is this concatenation taking place?

Comment: well, I think this should be enough, could you please let me know what exactly you need?

Comment: note that `<tspan>`  doesn't accept `<img>` as child  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan

Comment: hmm, that's what it is... then how can I add it?

Comment: Is the `tspan` inside a `td` or something? You could use prepend or prependto on the parent 'td' to create `<td><img><tspan></tspan></td>` or have you considered changing it from a `tspan` to something more relevant/useful?

Comment: Knocked off a point because you refuse to show us the surrounding code. Don't believe you should get a point for this.

Comment: @D.Shah, edited the code. It is inside `<svg><text>`

Comment: @DroidChris, please see edition.

Comment: @SeattleSam why not prepend the image to the `<text>` before the `<tspan>` so the image and tspan are siblings rather than the image being a child of the tspan?

Answer (score -1):

So it appears that this `<tspan>` tag should only be part of a text element...

Within a `<text>` element, text and font properties and the current text position can be adjusted with absolute or relative coordinate values by including a tspan element. ... The attribute rotate was implemented in Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4 / Thunderbird 3.3 / SeaMonkey 2.1).

So perhaps you need to do move the `<img>` tag outside of the text element.

Here is the HTML I just parsed:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/INxnl.png'  width='600px' height='100px'>
    </body>
</html>
```

The image tag loads the following image:

[image]

The image includes the text.